# KeyError: 'response'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

VK Api + Python.

Вот код:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

import random

import os

import glob

from time import sleep



vk_key = '5757'

group_id = 575755  # ID паблика

pics = glob.glob('*.jpg')



if len(pics) == 0:

    print('Нет изображений для постинга')

    exit()



pic2post = random.choice(pics)



url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id=%d&v=5.28&access_token=%s' % (

    group_id, vk_key)



resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']

upload_url = resp['upload_url']

files = {'file1': open(pic2post, 'rb')}

resp = requests.post(upload_url, files=files)

resp = resp.json()

server = resp['server']

photo = resp['photo']

vkhash = resp['hash']

sleep(0.4)

url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?group_id=%s&server=%s&photo=%s&hash=%s&v=5.28&access_token=%s' % (

    group_id, server, photo, vkhash, vk_key)

resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']

resp = resp[0]

photo_id = resp['id']

owner_id = resp['owner_id']

atts = 'photo%s_%s' % (owner_id, photo_id)

sleep(0.4)

url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=%s&from_group=1&attachments=%s&v=5.28&access_token=%s' % (

    -group_id, atts, vk_key)

resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']

files = 0



os.remove(pic2post)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 21, in <module>
    resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']
KeyError: 'response'
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Весь код нужно прилагать всегда, если суть вопроса в нём

Comment: Чтобы дополнить вопрос, нажмите кнопку "править" под ним

Comment: проблема в том, что нет такого ключа ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Эникейщик прав, а вот чтобы ответить на вопрос "почему" хотелось бы видеть весь код

Comment: Попробуйте вывести весь `json` и посмотреть, что в нём вообще есть

Comment: Советую использовать библиотеку vk_api. С ней достаточно удобно работать и не потребуется таких больших заморочек.

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего в том json в котором вы хотите просмотреть `response`  нет такого раздела или он находится в каком-то разделе

Попробуйте вывести весь json и посмотреть его структуру